# How to see all predefined androidplot styles

Tags: android, styles, androidplot

I'm using androidplot 1.4.1 and I'd like to check all available predefined styles. In the quick start, they use style="@style/APDefacto.Dark". Where can I see other available styles? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the full list of styles in [style.xml](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/style.xml).  Additionally you can see the full list of attrs these styles draw from in [attrs.xml](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml).